# Trying to programmatically display a vector using blit

Tags: python, list, vector, blit

New to python and I am just trying to test out some stuff. From some research I think I need a list to store all the vector points

```
mlist1 = [
[7, 12],
[22, 31],
[4, 17]]
```

everything is good I test it out as a print to see.

```
print (mlist1);
```

but now I would like to use each element as a vector for a blit. So my code looked liked this

```
for number in mlist1:
    s=pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600));
    newInt = mlist1[number];
    s.blit(array_surface, newInt);
```

(got an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`)

I understand that blit needs an int, but is there any other function available or anything else I can do to achieve my goal? I am open to any and all suggestions(even if that means doing something different than what I am currently doing, I merely am doing this all from scratch with very little experience with python or vectors in this sense), thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Another point I would like to make is that I am trying to make a NavGraph so I need nodes, so this is essentially what will be nodes so if that affects anyone's answer/comments, just wanted to put that out there.

EDIT 2:

To clarify my question more I wanted to explain that I am essentially trying to pass a vector into a blit, but I need an integer. I am wondering if there is another function or something that I can use to basically pass the vector in instead of a integer and still have it draw in the window

Comment: `but now I would like to use each element as a vector for a blit.`

Comment: I am essentially trying to pass a vector into a blit, but I need an integer. To clarify more, I am wondering if there is another function or something that I can use to basically pass the vector in instead of a integer and still have it draw in the window.

Comment: @thefourtheye He meant - I can use to achieve my goal.

Comment: @DeveshSaini not that this has anything to do with my question, but my grammar was fine. 'Do' and 'use' can both be used and it still makes sense. I think some users just like to be picky, so I clarified my question more.

Comment: there  error man acutally ur passing a list to a list as index.

Comment: ok well yeah I am confused(why I asked SO). I read that I should be storing the vectors in a list, so that's why it's like that.

Comment: see what u want to pass into newInt?

Comment: @thefourtheye not quite sure what you mean or what your intentions are replying to this question, but please, let's keep this professional and just strictly advice or answers to my question please.

Comment: @user3577516 what u want to pass into newInt

Comment: @SundarNataraj I declared newInt solely as an attempt that maybe it didn't like me directly passing a list in there. From my experiences with other languages, sometimes it prefers when you assign a variable to a temporary one so that's why I did that.

Comment: @user3577516 my question what u want to intialise to newInt.its ok . i want to know what u want to pass into newInt is it [7,12]

Comment: Okay, let me explain something else because I feel like you're focusing in on something that does not have much relevance, and perhaps there is a communication error between my question, so basically I am trying to A) store a list of vectors and B) then use those vectors in a blit to draw the Surface in the window. Normally I would do that by hard-coding each one like this: node1 = (50, 50); but I want them in a list, or whatever else I need, I am only doing lists because I read online somewhere I should, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure blit is what you want.  This draws circles at your co-ordinates.  I suggest looking through the pygame tutorials some more.

```
import pygame

mlist1 = [
    (7, 12),
    (22, 31),
    (4, 17)]

s = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

for point in mlist1:
    pygame.draw.circle(s, (255, 0, 0), point, 5)

pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: ok this works. I read that blit basically is what draws whatever you want on the screen, in my case I have been using a surface. I am trying to create a navgraph so should I still be doing this way? I tested it and it works, by the way, thank you very much very helpful. I did read up on draw.circle but I tested it out and it didn't work quite the way I wanted it to. Thank you again.

Comment: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit -- blit is used to combine bitmaps, e.g., copy an image to a display area.  I'm not an expert in this area, but I'd suggest sticking with the pygame.draw.* operations initially.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
s = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600));
for point in mlist1:
    s.blit(array_surface, point);
```

Comment: okay this is close except it doesn't actually draw anything on screen. I think my problem is that I may be doing the list wrong,  I am trying to A) store a list of vectors and B) then use those vectors in a blit to draw the Surface in the window. Normally I would do that by hard-coding each one like this: node1 = (50, 50); but I want them in a list, or whatever else I need, I am only doing lists because I read online somewhere I should, but I could be wrong.

Comment: However, I get no errors, and it tests right so I think this is really close but my declaration of vectors might be wrong.

Comment: ok well then points. I was taught that a vector is an x and y coordinate so yeah, point is what I need then.